# Is this a good concatList(List A, List B) function in C?

Tags: c

Is this a good `concatList` method? It seems alright to me but when I test it Microsoft Visual Studio says `Unable to start the program. Access denied.` I want to see if it is the method itself and if it not, I will reduce the possibilities of why my main program only runs when that method is not tested.

```
List concatList(List A, List B) {
    if (A == NULL || B == NULL) {
        printf("Error: List ADT: Attempted to call concatList(List A, List B) when a List argument is NULL\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        List concatedList = newList; //create the new List which we will return
        int lengthh = 0;

        Node As = A->front;
        while (As != NULL) { //go through and append everything in List A to the new List
            append(concatedList, As->data);
            As = As->next;
            lengthh++;
        }
        
        Node Bs = B->front;
        while (Bs != NULL) { //go through and append everything in List B to the new List
            append(concatedList, Bs->data);
            Bs = Bs->next;
            lengthh++;
        }

        concatedList->front = A->front;
        concatedList->back = B->back;
        concatedList->length = lengthh;

        return concatedList; //return the new, concatenated, List
    }
}
```

Important parts of my List.c:

```
typedef struct nodeObj {
    int data;
    struct nodeObj *prev;
    struct nodeObj *next;
} nodeObj;

//private Node type
typedef nodeObj *Node;

//private ListObj tyoe
typedef struct ListObj {
    Node front;
    Node back;
    Node cursor;
    int length;
    int index;
} ListObj;

List newList(void) {
    List Z;
    Z = malloc(sizeof(ListObj));
    Z->front = Z->back = NULL;
    Z->length = 0;
    Z->index = -1;
    Z->cursor = NULL;
    return (Z);
}

int front(List L) {
    // If list is NULL, throw error
    if (L == NULL) {
        printf("List Error: calling front() on NULL List reference\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // If no elements in L, throw error
    if (length(L) <= 0) {
        printf("List Error: front() called on empty List\n");
    }

    // Else return head element of L
    return L->front->data;
}

void append(List L, int data) {
    Node N = newNode(data);

    // If list is NULL, throw error
    //if (L == NULL) {
    //    printf("List Error: calling append() on a NULL List reference\n");
    //    exit(1);
    //}

    // If tail of list L is NULL, set front and back of list L to N, then set cursor to back of L
    if (L->back == NULL) {
        L->front = L->back = N;
        L->cursor = L->back;
    } else {
        // If List L is not empty, then

        // Set next value of list L to N
        L->back->next = N;

        // Set the prior value of N to the tail of L
        N->prev = L->back;

        // Set tail of L to Node N
        L->back = N;

        // Remove value from N
        N->next = NULL;
    }

    // Increment the length of L
    L->length++;
}
```

Comment: Where does `List` com from? Should this be c or c++? Pick a language please, they're fundamentally different.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you have a bug here:

```
List concatedList = newList;
```

I expect it to be:

```
List concatedList = newList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you encounter is probably unrelated to the code, but rather to how you invoke he program.

Meanwhile, there are some issues in your `concatList` function:

- the new list should be allocated by calling the `NewList` constructor:

  ```
  List concatedList = newList();
  ```
- there is no need to compute the length manually, `append` already performs the necessary bookkeeping.
- updating the `front` and `back` pointers as you do is incorrect. You actually corrupt the `concatedList` object. There is no need to update the fields in `concatedList` at all.

Here is a corrected version:

```
List concatList(List A, List B) {
    if (A == NULL || B == NULL) {
        printf("Error: List ADT: Attempted to call concatList(List A, List B) when a List argument is NULL\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        // create the new List which we will return
        List concatedList = newList();

        // go through and append everything in List A to the new List
        Node As = A->front;
        while (As != NULL) {
            append(concatedList, As->data);
            As = As->next;
        }
        
        // go through and append everything in List B to the new List
        Node Bs = B->front;
        while (Bs != NULL) {
            append(concatedList, Bs->data);
            Bs = Bs->next;
        }

        // return the new, concatenated, List
        return concatedList;
    }
}
```

Also note these remarks:

- `List` is not defined in the posted source code. I assumed the definition to be `typedef listObj *List;`
- It is confusing and error prone to hide pointers behind `typedef`s.
- you do not test for potential `malloc()` failure.